# redis timeout increasing set min threads and connection timeout does not resolve

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Redis timeout errors occurring in my application when processing thousands of messages

I have an application which takes in contracts, creates a key and value in redis for each contract before it's being sent to Kafka. If I get the same contract, application checks if the key exists and the value is same to the previous contract, the messages is not processed further.

I have tried increasing the connectTimeout and connectRetry in the connection string. Have also tried setting the minthreads in the program main method.

The outer application which calls Redis within is configured by setting min threads and the connection sting with increased connectTimeout and connectRety

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 300);
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

"Redis": {
    "ConnectionString": "localhost:6379",connectTimeout=10000,connectRetry=5
}




public class RedisConnectionFactory
    {
        public static ConnectionMultiplexer GetConnection(string connectionString)
        {
            var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(connectionString);
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
        }
    }
```

public interface IRedisDataAgent
    {
        string GetStringValue(string key);

```
    void SetStringValue(string key, string value);

    void DeleteStringValue(string key);
}
```

public class RedisDataAgent : IRedisDataAgent
    {
        private static IDatabase _database;

```
    public RedisDataAgent(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connection = RedisConnectionFactory.GetConnection(configuration.GetSection("Redis")["ConnectionString"]);

        _database = connection.GetDatabase();
    }

    public string GetStringValue(string key)
    {
        return _database.StringGet(key);
    }

    public void SetStringValue(string key, string value)
    {
        _database.StringSet(key, value);
    }

    public void DeleteStringValue(string key)
    {
        _database.KeyDelete(key);
    }
}
```

Application is expected not to throw any timeout errors no matter how many thousands of messages being processed.

I have increased the min threads to 1000, but still throwing errors. No matter how much I increase, it's still throwing errors

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing SET (5000ms),
IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=300,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1018,Free=31749,Min=1000,Max=32767)

Comment: This helped me, I did not have targetFramework in my httpRuntime tag in my web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993854/all-redis-commands-timing-out-when-using-azure-cac.html